# Why does this SQL query with a subquery require a GROUP BY for a column that is restricted to a single value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why does the following SQL query fail?

```
SELECT
    a.time,
    SUM(a.x)*(SELECT SUM(b.weight) FROM b WHERE b.id = a.id AND b.time = a.time) AS z
FROM 
    a
WHERE
    a.id = 'FOO'
GROUP BY 
    a.time
```

With SQL Server 2016, I get an error

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>   Column 'a.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

The error message means that SQL Server thinks that the inner query can yield results for multiple `a.id` so it doesn't know which one to produce. I don't understand why it thinks that, because the `WHERE` of the outer query limits `a.id` to a single value.

I can make the error go away by either adding `a.id` to the `GROUP BY` of the outer query, or by replacing `a.id` by `'FOO'` in the inner query. Both are undesirable in my application, where many queries like this one are created dynamically from prefabricated pieces, and the inner query should preferably be fixed (i.e., no on-the-fly insertion of literal `'FOO'`), and the outer query should preferably be ignorant of the details of the inner query (i.e., no adding of `a.id` to the `GROUP BY` of the outer query just because it is used by the inner query).

Can this problem be solved without making the inner and outer queries more aware of each other's details?

EDIT: The `time` and `id` fields are part of the primary keys of both tables.

Comment: You already seem to know why.  You explain it perfectly.   Without knowing the limitations of your application, it's hard to answer.  How drastically can you change the query?

Comment: a.id = 'FOO' is only guaranteed to return one record, if there is a unique index on that field.  I am not sure though whether, under standard SQL rules, the compiler is obliged to examine whether there is such a unique constraint on a field in a where clause in order to remove the requirement for it being included in the GROUP BY.  I suspect not!

Comment: Why does MSSQL think that the inner query can yield results for multiple `a.id` even though the outer query restricts `a.id` to a single value?

Comment: I think this would be an exceptionally *narrow* optimization to invest time in, to have a cardinality analysis on the outer query be used as part of the compilation of the inner query, to allow an exemption from a general rule.

Comment: @Jonathan Willcock: So the answer to my "why" question is: "because the SQL compiler hasn't been made smart enough for that".  Regrettable, but clear.

Comment: Select top 1 if you want to blink to the SQL Server saying "trust me there will be only one record" and that's it :)

Comment: Also you set "part of the primary key" not the PK itself what doesn't guarantee the uniqueness for a single column in a constraint at all

Comment: I am sure @Damien_The_Unbeliever is right. Especially so since as in your case it is very easy to get round the issue by moving the where to the inner query. It wouldn't be top of my list of priorities, don't even think it would make the footnotes :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be interested to see if anyone has a better solution, but I've done something like this in the past to solve a similar problem.

```
SELECT
 a.time,
 SUM(a.x)*(SELECT SUM(b.weight) FROM b WHERE b.id = MIN(a.id) AND b.time = a.time) AS z
FROM a
WHERE
  a.id='FOO'
GROUP BY a.time
```

Since you can be confident a.id can only be 1 value, the min will be that value.

Comment: I thought of this solution, too, but worried that `MIN(a.id)` might get evaluated before the `a.id='Foo'` restriction.  There are multiple values of `a.id` in the database.

Comment: The select part of the query runs after everything else, so a.id will be filtered before the min is taken.

Answer (score 0):

Try two steps:

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT
  a.time,
  SUM(a.x) AS z
FROM a
WHERE
  a.id='FOO'
GROUP BY a.time
)

select a.time
    ,a.z*(SELECT SUM(b.weight) FROM b WHERE b.id = a.id AND b.time = a.time) as z
from cte a
```